# Is deuce STM type safe?

Tags: type-safety, stm, pi-calculus

I have written a **JAVA** library for **pi calculus** which utilizes **Deuce STM** for managing concurrent processes. 
I further wish to prove the type safety of my library. 
Is Deuce STM library type safe? If yes, some links for the same would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by type safe?

Comment: Type safety means that, well-typed programs cannot go wrong. In other words, if a program compiles successfully, it will never break at run-time because of type errors.

Comment: Deuce doesn't suppose to break programs on type safety